# Networkx: Nodes as Objects OR Nodes as ID's with Dictionary Attribute Tables

Tags: python, networkx

Which is the most efficient in terms of memory management and computation speed?

The simple test below suggests it is slightly better to store attributes within nodes as a python object vs. dictionary lookups through attribute tables. Will this always the case due to how the memory is allocated?

As a test I constructed a simple example:

```
class country():
    def __init__(self, name, gdp):
        self.name = name
        self.gdp = gdp
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name)

#Country Objects
countries = dict()
countries['AUS'] = country('AUS', 2000)
countries['USA'] = country('USA', 10000)
countries['ZWE'] = country('ZWE', 13)

#Attribute Dictionary
gdp = dict()
gdp['AUS'] = 2000
gdp['USA'] = 10000
gdp['ZWE'] = 13
```

Constructing Networks:

```
#Nodes as ID's
G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_nodes_from(countries.keys())
G1.nodes()

#Nodes as Objects
G2 = nx.Graph()
for c in countries.keys():
    G2.add_node(countries[c])
G2.nodes()
```

Running %timeit in IPython:

**G1f()**

```
#Lookup Data from Strings Network
def G1f():
    for n in G1.nodes():
        print "Node: %s" % n
        print "\tGDP: %s" % gdp[n]
%timeit G1f
```

**Output for G1f():**

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 26.4 ns per loop
```

**G2f()**

```
#Lookup Data from Objects 
def G2f():
    for n in G2.nodes():
        print "Node: %s" % n.name
        print "\tGDP: %s" % n.gdp
%timeit G2f
```

**Output for G2f()**

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 ns per loop
```

---

**Updated**

**G3f() [from answers]**

```
G3 = nx.Graph()
for c,v in gdp.items():
    G3.add_node(c, gdp=v)
def G3f():
    for n,d in G3.nodes(data=True):
        print "Node: %s" % n
        print "\tGDP: %s" % d['gdp']
```

**Output for G13f():**

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 63 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use node attributes like this:

```
import networkx as nx
#Attribute Dictionary
gdp = dict()
gdp['AUS'] = 2000
gdp['USA'] = 10000
gdp['ZWE'] = 13

G3 = nx.Graph()
for c,v in gdp.items():
    G3.add_node(c, gdp=v)

print G3.nodes(data=True)

def G3f():
    for n,d in G3.nodes(data=True):
        print "Node: %s" % n
        print "\tGDP: %s" % d['gdp']
```

It's not clear to me the test timings are very significant.  Unless this is a very huge problem (maybe someday everyone will have their own country!) there might not be much difference in speed or memory.  I suspect that the overhead of creating many small custom objects (country()) will end up using more memory and time.

Comment: Thanks - I am interested in timing because I would also like to attach attributes to edges and the number of edges can become very large. I will add %timeit for G3f() above as another option.